# Propose please an open data for graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph

I should to prepare myself for upcoming task which consist of a lot of graphs.
I need some data (available in free domain) to train myself.
Bigger - is better...
could you suggest some open data resource?
I'll appreciate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer for your `could you suggest some open data resource?` and not for `which consist of a lot of graphs`. So, plz, keep it in mind.

[Here](http://data.gov.au/) (data.gov.au) you can find a huge datasets (864!) of a different types in a different formats (txt, csv, xml, ). You will find a *Finance*, *Industry*, *Geography*, etc. datasets.

In other case, if you want some special (and meaningful data, for example, global population density) you can see this (a bit outdated, but usefull) [source](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/where_to_find_open_data_on_the.php) from readwriteweb.com.

And one more source: "[Open Governmental Datasets](http://linkeddata.deri.ie/node/72)" - it's worth to see it indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You can visit http://snap.stanford.edu/data/ . It contains many different kind of network or graph data.